# What does it mean when folder items are shown in bold lettering in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, font, high-sierra

I see some items in Finder show up as bold and I wonder what that means. The example I have attached is somewhere under `~/Library`. It's the most recent place I've seen this, not the only place. It also happens outside of `~/` and its subdirectories. It looks like a feature more than a bug. I wondered if it had to do with Git (maybe MacOS High Sierra shows Git statuses in Finder by default the way Ubuntu does), but no. I wondered if it's a Time Machine thing too (i.e. files not yet backed up may be shown in bold). I don't have a definitive answer. I haven't seen this advertised as a feature anywhere on Apple's site or any similar questions in Apple's support site. If this is a feature, I'd really like to know what it's for.

Thanks!

[image: bold and regular font]

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say it's not a feature, and is probably some rendering bug.

Comment: I turned LCD font smoothing on and off. With font smoothing turned on, everything is bold. Looks like a rendering issue.

Answer (score 1):

It makes it bold when the file name is truncated due to lack of space. If you move the horizontal bar to the right to see the full name it will un-bold.

Comment: Just tried it, couldn't replicate this behavior. Are you sure?