# Finder file names with non-standard characters are bold in High Sierra

Tags: finder, font, high-sierra, bug

Why are all file names in Finder that have non standard characters such as accents or umlauts bold in High Sierra Finder?

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: possibly related - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304344/what-does-it-mean-when-folder-items-are-shown-in-bold-lettering-in-finder - but no answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Similar but mine's specifically related to the special characters. I can get the bold to go away if I remove them.

Comment: In System Preferences > Input Sources, which language do you have selected? Do you have alternate languages installed?

Comment: @IconDaemon: Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources = U.S.